# Floating point arithmetic not working properly as expected in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL query where I'm trying to fetch top 2 versions of every App in the table using row_number() and partition keyword to fetch top 2 version of every App.

The query I written is:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         *, 
         row_number() over (partition by appName order by version desc) as version_rank 
     from deployments) as ranks 
where 
    version_rank <= 2
```

The query is working totally as expected as the table data is as:

```
AppID   appName   BundleID   version
-------------------------------------
123     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.7
124     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.8
125     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.9
126     abc       com.abc    1.3.1
127     abc       com.abc    1.3.6
128     abc       com.abc    1.3.9
```

The result is:

```
AppID   appName   BundleID   version
-------------------------------------
125     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.9
124     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.8
128     abc       com.abc    1.3.9
127     abc       com.abc    1.3.6
```

But this case is failing and I'm not sure why is that.

For instance if the versions are 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, the `version`'s datatype is `varchar`.

The output I'm getting is:

```
AppID   appName   BundleID   version
------------------------------------
125     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.9
124     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.8
```

It's like SQL Server is treating .10 as .1 and comparison is made, but what I want is output like:

```
AppID   appName   BundleID   version
-------------------------------------
125     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.10
124     xyz       com.xyz    1.4.9
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version is a string, not a number.  If the following is true:

- The first and second parts are both single digits.
- The third part varies and is not zero padded.

Then, the following will work:

```
select *
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by appName order by len(version) desc, version desc) as version_rank
      from deployments
    ) d
where version_rank <= 2;
```

I suspect that this covers your use-case, so you don't have to use anything more complicated.

EDIT:

Assuming you have exactly three parts:

```
select *
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by appName
                                order by v1.val1 desc, v2.val2 desc, v2.val3 desc
                               ) as version_rank
      from deployments d cross apply
           (values (try_convert(int, left(d.version, charindex('.', d.version))),
                    stuff(d.version, 1, charindex('.', d.version), '')
           ) v1(val1, rest) cross apply
           (values (try_convert(int, left(v1.rest, charindex('.', v1.rest))),
                    try_convert(int, stuff(v.rest, 1, charindex('.', v.rest), ''))
           ) v2(val2, val3) cross apply

    ) d
where version_rank <= 2;
```

Comment: it's not necessary that the first and second part will be single digit, will it work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
AppId int, 
appName varchar(20), 
BundleId varchar(20), 
version varchar(20)
);

insert into @t(AppId, appName, BundleId, version)
values
(123, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', '1.14.7'),
(124, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', '1.4.8'),
(125, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', '1.4.19'),
(126, 'abc', 'com.abc', '0.3.1'),
(127, 'abc', 'com.abc', '10.3.4'),
(128, 'abc', 'com.abc', '2.3.19');

--only numbers and dots
select *
from @t
order by cast('/'+version+'/' as hierarchyid)--try_cast(concat('/', version, '/') as hierarchyid)

--old days...numbers&dots only
select *
from @t
order by cast(parsename(version, 3) as int), cast(parsename(version, 2) as int), cast(parsename(version, 1) as int);

insert into @t(AppId, appName, BundleId, version)
values
(123, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', '_a1.1xyz4.d7'),
(124, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', 'a1.4!z.f8'),
(124, 'xyz', 'com.xyz', ' a1.4!z.f8');


--split dots, make it safe, max 5chars separated by dots
select *,
    p1 = right('00000'+ left(version+'..', charindex('.', version+'..', 1)-1), 5), 
    p2 = right('00000'+ substring(version+'..', charindex('.', version+'..', 1)+1, charindex('.', version+'..', charindex('.', version+'..', 1)+1)- charindex('.', version+'..', 1) - 1), 5),
    p3 = right('00000'+ reverse(left(reverse(version)+'..', charindex('.', reverse(version)+'..', 1)-1)), 5)
from @t
order by p1, p2, p3;
```